# Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server aborted: read failed

Tags: fastcgi

Using FastCGI on my dedicated server (Debian).

I now have following error, sometimes (total random behavior !!).
Resulting to white page (error 500).

[Tue May 27 13:02:09 2014] [error] [client 85.68.183.29] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/php5.external" aborted: read failed, referer: [...]
[Tue May 27 13:02:09 2014] [error] [client 85.68.183.29] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/php5.external", referer: [...]

I cannot find any other errors linked to this (any PHP details, MySQL SQL error, nothing else !!!).

Any idea to prevent this ugly bug?
Should I come back to mod-php5 ??

Answer (score 2):

You might try following the suggestion on this page: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/highload-php-en/4F79Pco-2eg/_tfPMiLFzg4J

Copied here for reference:

> Use -idle-timeout paramater on "FastCgiExternalServer" line to solve
>   this problem.
>
> My FastCgiExternalServer line: FastCgiExternalServer
>   /var/run/fastcgi/USERNAME-fcgi -appConnTimeout 10 -idle-timeout 250
>   -socket /var/run/fastcgi/USERNAME.socket -pass-header Authorization
>
> More information in mod_fastcgi doc:
>   http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html

Comment: Thanks, but this solution increase idle time to 250sc (default is 30sc). I don't want to do this because this will not solve my problem: why is the server take more than 30sc to execute a request...

I'd like to find the problem, but as there is no PHP error log or MySQL timeout, and as this is a random behavior (not happening everytime on same page, only a few times each day), I don't know how to proceed!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I figured out that there was some recursive dependency that resulted in not enough memory being available. Resolving the recursive dependency removed the issue.